# Ajax function try catch block not correct

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the code below but I'm not sure if my try-catch block is actually right. Can someone guide me please?

```
var upload = new FormData($("#video_upload")[0]);
 

    try {
            $.ajax({
                url: "files/video_upload",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                type: 'POST',
                data: upload,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.filesToUpload').empty();
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    alert (‘Upload Failed.');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using try-catch around ajax. You can use the error function return by ajax request when the request fails.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "files/video_upload",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                type: 'POST',
                data: upload,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.filesToUpload').empty();
                },
                //Add this
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
```

Comment: I'm new ta ajax and I want the function to continue running if there is an error and not crash. Will the error:function allow that please?

Comment: Yes that would work but you have to be careful to apply intervals on AJAX as it's an asynchronous call.